# Django: Cannot assign object: "VoterCode.region" must be a "Region" instance

Tags: django, django-forms, foreign-keys

I am quite new at Django, and I am trying to make a form with a foreign key. I take only one foreign key from the form, and I assign the rest of the values. I understand I am trying to save an object, not an instance. 
I thought that a query is getting a collection of instances (a query set of instances), and even if it has only one element I have to always take the first. This is what I tried to do, but it did not work:

```
return Region.objects.filter(name = region_name)[:1].get()
```

Here is my form:

```
class VoterCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    election = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Election.objects.all(), empty_label="Select an election")
    class Meta:
        model = VoterCode
        fields = ('election',)
```

Here is my view:

```
def populate_voter_codes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VoterCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            election = form.instance.election
            form.save(commit=False)
            VoterCode.populate_voter_codes(election)
            return redirect('elections')
    else:
        form = VoterCodeForm()
    return render(request, 'admin_interface/populate_voter_codes.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is how I save the values:

```
def postcode_to_region(postcode):
        ...some processing...
        return Region.objects.filter(name = region_name)[:1].get()

def populate_voter_codes(the_election):
    data = requests.get(url = "http://t2a.co/rest/?output=json&method=person_search&api_key=test").json()
    data = data["person_list"]
    i = 1
    for person in data:
        voter_code = VoterCode.generate_voter_code()
        #print(person["postcode"])
        region = VoterCode.postcode_to_region(person["postcode"]);
        entry = VoterCode(id=i, code=voter_code, election = the_election, region = region)
        entry.save()
        i += 1
```

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: Have you tried `Region.objects.filter(name=region_name).first()` ?

Comment: Yes, does not work. I think I don't realize what the actual problem is. When  i print the first element, it prints "region object", so I don't understand what they mean by instance..

Comment: Have you implemented the `__str__` (py 3) or `__unicode__` (py 2) method inside the `Region` model ? You should in order to get a nice represntation of the returned object!

Comment: I didn't know what that was, I added __str__ in my model, but I am not sure how it can help. I don't have the auth_user table so I don't know if that back-end log in works (I had to make the tables myself because of the project structure - multiple databases). Is there any other place I can see clear errors?

Comment: You said that: *I don't understand what they mean by instance*. The solution to this (`"region object"`) is to implement one of the 2 methods I mentioned inside your `Region` model.

Comment: I put `__str__` in both region and voter_code, but I have the same error as before. I see in command line that it shows me the region. `Cannot assign "[<Region:126 Cardiff Central>]": "voterCode.region" must be a region instance` . So clearly getting the first element does not work, I still see an array with one element (unless the square brackets mean something else?). Anyway, thanks for the `__str__` tip, it's clearly useful for debugging.